# PostgreSQL position based attribution

Tags: arrays, postgresql, sorting, google-analytics

I am looking to create a position based attribution model using PostgreSQL but haven't been able to get it correctly.

I have tried different methods but the closest I have gotten to is the even distribution model, so, giving all marketing channels an even credit for each conversion.

Here is my last click model for a reference on the table structure I need, this assigns a full one to each of the last channels in the channel_path (with the count(distinct order_id):

```
    select
            coalesce(unique_channel_path[array_length(unique_channel_path,1)],
            'not_tracked') as source,
            order_date,
            count(distinct order_id) as count_orders

    from base_conversions  cvr
    group by 1,2,3,4,5,6
    order by 2 desc;
```

The attribution I would like to have is one that assigns 0.4 to the first channel, 0.2 to all the intermediate channels and 0.4 to the last one.

Example:

order_id                channel_path
    1       array['seo','refferal','social_media']
    2       array['seo','social_media']
    3       array['social_media','sem','display','seo']
    4       array['social_media']

result:

```
channel          credit

display          0.4+0.5+0.4+0.1 = 1.4
refferal         0.2             = 0.2
social_media     0.4+0.5+0.4+1   = 2.3
sem              0.1             = 0.1
seo              0.4+0.5+0.4     = 1.3
```

Notice how sem gets only 0.1 since it belongs to the middle category of order_id 3 along with sem, so to recap:

all first channels get 0.4, all middle ones get 0.2 all together and all last channels get 0.4 for a total of 1.0

**In summary:**

The final result I am seeking is a table which has the following structure:

```
Date      Channel      Weight
 1          sem         1.4
 2        display       1.0
 3          seo         0.4
 .
 .
 .
```

Taking into account that what I have arrays with each of the channels in the order they appeared for every order:

```
order_id                  unique_channel_path
   1             array['display','seo','social_media'....]
   2             array['sem','seo','seo'....]
   .
   .
```